# /bin/sh: 1: python: not found while running docker container

Tags: python, docker

This is my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 
ADD ./file.py ./
CMD python file.py
```

I am building using below command:

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

And running using this:

```
docker run myimage
```

And then getting below error after running:

```
/bin/sh: 1: python: not found
```

What should I do so the file file.py will be executed using python ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I want the file to be executed. Let me update the question.

Comment: Do you know that the ubuntu:14.04 image is *supposed* to have a `python` interpreter (under that name, not `python2` or `python3` or such) in-PATH? (i could check, but that would mean a fairly lengthy download).

Comment: python is probably not in the path when in the docker env. Can you put the absolute path?

Comment: I dont know, till now I am assuming that python is there but I did some docker mistake. So, what should I do now ?

Comment: I tried /usr/bin/python instead of python still it didnt work. 
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found

Comment: Well, I'd start by running a shell inside your container, and looking at what software it does and doesn't have. Is there a Python interpreter? Where is it? What's its name? If you need to `RUN` an `apt-get` command to install it, figure that out and add it to your Dockerfile.

Comment: Ok thanks. ........

Comment: Ubuntu docker image doesn't come with python installed, you need to add a few RUN command installing python on your Dockerfile, for the list of command steps, see this answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/101595

Comment: @EwyynTomato, ...I'm abliged to consider that particular ("build it from source") answer fairly awful. I mean, there are distro-maintained packages available [<- I was wrong here]; not using them means one is moving into unsupported space (if you have a problem with a Python you built yourself and ask Canonical support for help with it, the answer will be "tough luck").

Comment: ...using a 3rd-party PPA means there's someone who's not you who's (at least on a volunteer basis) taking on the responsibility for making sure any necessary patches are applied, dependencies reflected, that the package plays well with others, &c; rolling it yourself means there's no support at all.

Comment: Use official Python Docker image: `FROM python:3.5`.

Comment: @skovorodkin, ...add that as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use the official [`python` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python):

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY ./file.py ./
CMD python file.py
```